# I cannot run Runner Cucumber Reports

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I tried create a test reports. But I can not this case.

I tried research and fix this but I dont know what happens. Can you help me?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYgVj.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5v5k.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mzNd.png

Comment: Could you please copy the code into your question instead of posting images? That will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your scenario didn't execute (based on the last image). It has 6 undefined steps. Maybe you need to focus on fixing that first.

Answer (score 0):

In @CucumberOtions features should contain the path to your feature file like

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/Feature.feature"
```

The .feature file usually is located in resources package
glue option in @CucubmerOptions should contain name of the packege with the stepDefinitions file:

```
glue = {"stepDefinitions"}
```